# Xamarin.Forms Android Deploy

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and everything works fine in the emulator, but when I try to deploy to LivePLay I get errors like this.

```
Error       Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/system.security.principal.windows/4.4.0/ref/netstandard2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll".
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0
```

For these .dlls

```
System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
System.Security.AccessControl.dll
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.dll
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
```

So far I've tried pairing two devices and gotten the same results. App crashes on load if I try creating an apk and installing. Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that live player isn't actually a "real" android (or iOS)  environment. Similar to the Xamarin Previewer, that thing only works as long as you are doing "basic" stuff.

Once you start including Resources, use locally stored sql databases, write custom renderers, use dependency services and build views which rely on actual data, you are most likely to get dozens of exceptions.

The thing is: You can spend a lot of time and effort into making your code compatible with the live player environment or you just use an emulator or a real device for debugging.